# Android Media database direct access from code

Tags: android, database, cursor, media

Can I access android MediaProvider (Images & Videos) databases directly from my code rather then through a content provider ?

I'm planning to have my own Cursor implementation so inside it I want to access the media databases directly, possible or android does not allow it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, no.  The system databases for media are not directly available to applications, and so you must use a Content Provider to access the data they contain.

The purpose of Content Providers are to make database content available across applications, without actually exposing the underlying databases.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can access Android media provider from code this is the link which helps you

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html